# Selecting links in side nav and menu bar?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I am writing test cases and would like to test that all the links in the navigation bars work. How can I go about testing them?

When I run:

```
visit welcome_index_path
page.find("li", text: "Companies").click
```

I get an error saying that two elements matching css "li" with text "Companies"? How can I break it down further to find the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using Capybara based on the syntax, in which case you would wrap your call in a `within` block. For example..

```
visit welcome_index_path
within("#id_of_whichever_menu_youre_testing") do
    page.find("li", text: "Companies").click
end
```

There are more examples on the capybara readme https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara